# Vim format source code from Visual mode

Tags: vim

watching a screencast (can't link it since you need to have a peepcode pro subscription) I've seen a developer indenting his source code (a ruby file) graphically using the visual mode inside vim. He did the following steps: press "v" selecting lines and then pressing something else I didn't get (because there is no representation of what's being pressed on the keyboard), then he got the whole source perfectly indented, without the need to write something on the command line.

Is there a plugin you know to do it that way from visual mode?

Comment: I don’t know how their screencasts are for Ruby or whatever else they teach but their Vim screencasts are horrible, IMO. If you are looking for quality Vim screencasts, check out http://vimcasts.org by Drew Neil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can press = in visual mode to automatically indent your code.

Or you can use > and < in visual mode to change the indentation level
of the selected code.

Answer (score 1):

This plugin does exactly what you want: https://github.com/Chiel92/vim-autoformat.

Answer (score 0):

That would be `V(motion)=`.

See `:help =` for details.